# Fixing referencing "/" (root) for assets when site is moved to subdirectory

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, web

I have a site which is currently in public_html and throughout the code assets (images, css, js, etc) are referenced via /asset_folder/asset which due to the "/" at the beginning ensures the browser goes to root and works through the directories.

I need to move the whole site to a subdirectory and run another site in parallel in another subdirectory, so they will be public_html/website_one and public_html/website_two.

Is it possible to add a htaccess file or something to each site (subdirectory) that ensures that if a "/" root is referenced, it stays within the site's subfolder?

Kind regards
Liam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add

```
<base href="http://www.yoursite.com/website_one/">
```

in the head tag of any page on website one, and

```
<base href="http://www.yoursite.com/website_two/">
```

which will set the "root" of any relative path.

A possibly better option would be to turn each site into a subdomain, so insead of

```
http://www.yoursite.com/website_one/
```

you would have

```
http://www.website_one.yoursite.com
```

and then all the links would work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a relative path, I mean, don't put the "/" at the beginning of the url.

If you're using now:

- /index.html
- /images/image1.png
- /html/section1.html
- /scripts/jsfile.js

Change it to:

- index.html
- images/image1.png
- html/section1.html
- scripts/jsfile.js

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately there are so many files that are using the reference so I didn't want to go through each individual file changing all of the references as it will take a long time. Also there are many files at different levels, hence why the developer used "/" in the first place to reference the root.